# Bind WPF ComboBox to database record

Tags: wpf, combobox

I've got and update form that I've bound to a datatable in WPF.  I've got one Field in the Record STATUS that has only 3 possibilitye A for Archived, C for Current or D for Draft.  I would like to put a Combobox on the form that would show the text for the selected record and can Update the database if the user wants to change the status.  I have searched all over the web and have not found an easy way to do this.  Can someone out there give me a suggestion as to where to start?

Answer (score 0):

I didn't get any responses.  Reading it I didn't phrase the question very well.  But I found an answer to my question in another post.

```
<ComboBox SelectedValuePath="Tag" SelectedValue="{Binding Path=STATUS}">
<ComboBoxItem Tag="A">Archived</ComboBoxItem>
<ComboBoxItem Tag="C">Current</ComboBoxItem>
<ComboBoxItem Tag="D">Draft</ComboBoxItem>
</ComboBox>
```

If anybody else is having this problem this might help.